# OR condition in regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

I am trying to write a script which performs an OR function through regular expressions in Perl. I have written a code in which if string contains 'D' or 'E' followed by 'P' it should print "D or E followed by P" otherwise "D or E not followed by P". Suppose if I give $s = 'ABCDEABCDEPABCDEAB' it should print the else condition but I think my if statement is not working properly. Please help.

```
my $s = 'ABCDEABCDEPABCDEAB';
if ($s =~ /D|E(?=P)/) {
    print "D or E is followed by P";
} 
else {
    print "D or E is not followed by P";
}
```

Comment: I think for the above pattern, it should print the `if` part.. As you have an 'E' followed by 'P'...  ABCDEABCD**EP**ABCDEAB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ($s =~ /[DE]P/) {
    print "D or E is followed by P";
}
else {
    print "neither D nor E is followed by P";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of this. No group, no non-capture-group. Great.

Comment: @RohitJain: Thanks! I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is parenthesis related, try this:

`$s =~ m/(D|E)(?=P)/`

Moreover, I would like to say that in your string you have `EP` in position 9. So, it will evaluate `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Damian Conway's `Regexp::Debugger` and try the '`rxrx`' function. It steps you through every single character comparison in a regex match so you can see exactly what is matched against what and when. Very useful. It also runs under DOS in Windows (without the nice colours) if that is what you run perl on.